# Use selenium webdriver to execute exported json from selenium ide extension

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I would like to execute the exported JSON file from selenium ide using selenium webdriver (python).

I want users to be able to to use selenium ide to record/send their actions (exported JSON) and some values that would indicate what the page should/should not contain.

To do this automatically it would help greatly if the webdriver could run the exported json object.

Answer (score 0):

> if the webdriver could run the exported json object.

Web-driver can not run it, but the [selenium-ide-runner](https://www.npmjs.com/package/selenium-side-runner) can.